# Angular 1.5, typescript and gulp

Tags: angularjs, typescript, dependency-management

I have a project written in angular 1.x according this template by John Papa:
https://github.com/johnpapa/ng-demos/tree/master/modular.

Basically i use a gulp to build a minified js for production and another task (called 'index') that injects all the js src files (without minification) into the index.html file.

How should I change things now when adding typescript to my project?

specifically, my issue is when I have a class B which inherits from class A and they both on the same namespace.

how can I make sure that in the minified js file or in the index.html injection the order of the classes will be according the dependencies?

Note also this issue that I've opened for another template, a one that shows how to use typescript with Angular - https://github.com/johnpapa/hottowel-angular-typescript/issues/24

Many thanks!

Comment: I am using angular 1.5 but use gulp-order to build and then if you name files the certain way you can load the class B first and class A second. Don't know if it helps https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-order

Comment: if I understand this plugin, it forces me to manually maintain the load order...I don't like doing so :)

Comment: we're using requirejs and its r.js optimization utility. So typescript import statement compiles into requirejs define statement and r.js utility knows the correct order of files during minification.